# How to add link previews in django?

Tags: python, django, api-linkpreview

I'm doing a chat app in python Django and I Want to implement Link preview while typing that ink in chat box. Anybody familiar with this please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Link preview API service -  [1]: https://www.linkpreview.net/
Try this code .

```
$.ajax({
            url: "https://api.linkpreview.net",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {q: "message URL", key: 'your API key'},
            success: function (response) {
                let data=response;        
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
```